# What is a good way to maintain a backup of emails?

Tags: email, productivity

I want to be able to save my emails from various sources in a standard format and maintain a backup. An analog is taking pictures from multiple devices (e.g. cameras and smartphones) and saving all of them in a directory in JPEG format.

The issue with archives (using export feature from KMail that I mainly use or any other client) is that there is no easy way to determine if an email has been lost between two backups. An analogy is taking backups using `rsync`. To explain, let us say I keep two backups, B1 and B2 where the former is updated from my data source (e.g. my smartphone) and B2 is synched from B1 after a few days. It is easy to spot accidental deletions by doing dry runs in verbose plus delete extraneous files in destination mode, when doing the B1 to B2 sync. Related is also the problem of introducing email duplicates. Is there a smart way to save all emails?

Comment: In what form are your source (live) emails stored? IMAP? Exchange? Local mbox format `/var/mail/pdp` file? For example, if all your sources can be accessed with IMAP it's a relatively straightforward process to clone them regularly.

Comment: @roaima Yes, my emails are stored on an Exchange server. I download them using IMAP. Cloning regularly is one thing. I also want to catch inadvertent deletions.

Comment: How you you differentiate inadvertent deletions from intentional deletions?

Comment: Basically, from memory.

Answer (score 3):

The general case is that for a number of email messages taking (N) MB of disk space you will need (N) MB disk space to spot deletions, but up to (2N) MB disk space to recover them.

I use `mbsync` as a daily `cron` job to backup emails from Exchange, with this as the `.mbsyncrc` file:

```
# See http://www.benfrancom.com/2014/11/24/mutt-offline-with-mbsync/
#
IMAPAccount work
Host outlook.office365.com
User roaima@contoso.com
Pass donteventhinkaboutit
# PassCmd "gpg2 -q --for-your-eyes-only --no-tty -d ~/.mailpass.gpg"
UseIMAPS yes
CertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
PipelineDepth 5

IMAPStore work-remote
Account work

MaildirStore work-local
Path ~/.mbsync/work/
Inbox ~/.mbsync/work/INBOX

Channel work
Master :work-remote:
Slave :work-local:
Patterns "INBOX" "*"
# Patterns "INBOX" "Other" "Archive" "Drafts" "Deleted Items"
Create Slave
# Remove Slave
Expunge Slave
Sync Pull New ReNew Delete Flags
SyncState *
```

With IMAP, one of the requirements is that no message is allowed to be changed *in situ*; any changes require a message to be given a new fileidentifier. This means that you can safely use `ln` to replicate the current state to a backup before a synchronisation with `mbsync`:

```
cd "$HOME/.mbsync"
mkdir -p backup

cp -al work/* backup/
find backup -type f -name '.*' -delete
```

After the synchronisation you can compare the lists of emails like this:

```
cd "$HOME/.mbsync"
( cd work &&
    find . -type f \( -name '.*' -o -printf "%p\t%T+\t%y\t%#m\t%U\t%G\n" \) |
    sort 
) > work.list

( cd backup &&
    find . -type f \( -name '.*' -o -printf "%p\t%T+\t%y\t%#m\t%U\t%G\n" \) |
    sort 
) > backup.list

comm -3 work.list backup.list
```

It wouldn't be particularly hard to run `comm -23` and `comm -13` to generate lists of new and deleted messages, and then extract the `From`, `To`, `Subject` and `Date` headers for each to create a report.